# Spock Framework: How to create a customized Data Provider

Tags: java, spock, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spock-reports

I am working with:

- Spring MVC
- Spring MVC Test
- Spock Framework

About Spock working with `@Unroll` I have the following situation about the `where` block

I can have the following:

```
where: "Internal"

    uriRequestReport << [ControllerSupportTest.createUrl1(), ControllerSupportTest.createUrl2()]
    methodNameReport << [ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID, ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID ]
```

Here the part where that is *annoying* in some way is that the data must be similar about the amount of items or structure, in this case by 2.

I mean, the following fails:

```
where: "Internal"

    uriRequestReport << [ControllerSupportTest.createUrl1(), ControllerSupportTest.createUrl2()]
    methodNameReport << [ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID]
```

How you can see now `methodNameReport` has one item.

Spock throws an exception.

Since I can test many URLs, it makes verbose be repeating the `ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID` term many times as many times I use `ControllerSupportTest.createUrl#()` where # would be 5 for example

In some way I can handle in the following way:

Note: It is a *Java* class

```
public class MyDataSetUtil {

    private static final Integer COUNTER = 2;

    private MyDataSetUtil(){

    }

    public static List<String> uris(){
        String[] uris = new String[COUNTER];
        uris[0] = ControllerSupportTest.createUrl1()
        uris[1] = ControllerSupportTest.createUrl2()
    }

    public static String[] methodNames(){
        String[] methodNames = (String[])  
        createArray(ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID);
        return methodNames;
    }

    private static String[] createArray(String value){
        String[] objects = new String[COUNTER];
        for(int i=0; i<COUNTER; i++){
            objects[i] = value;
        }
        return objects;
    }

}
```

Until here I have two kinds of problems

1. I must control always the *counter*
2. If I add a new variable for the `where` block, such as `mediaType`, then I must create a new method such as `methodNames()`
3. Always I must repeat the same data for each item in the array such as `ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID`

For the two previous points, it is reflected as below:

For example:

```
public static String[] mediaTypes(){
        String[] mediaTypes = (String[]) createArray(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);      
        return mediaTypes;
    }
```

I need something more *practical*

I've read the following post from SO too

- [Spock: Reading Test Data from CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189342/spock-reading-test-data-from-csv-file)
- [Utility API - CSVReader](https://github.com/choonchernlim/util) (source code from above)

But for my situation I don't want use CSV *yet*.

Other approach is through SQL such as:

- [spock - Parameterizations.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/spock/wikis/Parameterizations.wiki)

But again, for my situation I don't want use SQL *yet*.

For me is more interesting this approach:

- [Spocklight: Write Our Own Data Provider](http://mrhaki.blogspot.pe/2014/06/spocklight-write-our-own-data-provider.html)

In that post he has:

```
where:
  [_, name, gender, expected] << new MultilineProvider(source: userData)
```

See the `MultilineProvider` code from the post.

therefore I want do the following:

```
[uriRequestReport, methodNameReport, moreVariablesifExists] << [MyDataSetUtil.theMethod()]
```

**Requirement**:

I want return through the `MyDataSetUtil.theMethod()`(see the line shown above) a collection where each item represent the same than

```
    uriRequestReport << [ControllerSupportTest.createUrl1(), ControllerSupportTest.createUrl2()]
    methodNameReport << [ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID, ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID ]
```

To let me easily add a new variable in the `where` block and update the Java class quickly and avoid repeat the same data many times.

What could be the best approach? Remember the code should be based in Java.

I did a research on Google without a solution.

If you have a better suggestion, it is welcome

Comment: Surprisingly, this question is not tagged to `java`.

Comment: My mistake... it has been fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Just write theMethod() that will return set of entries, where each entry has all required data for one test run. ArrayList of urls, ArrayList of methodnames and ArrayList of other data. Then put all lists in one big ArrayList or map and return this object.

```
{
 "urls":[list of urls]
 "methods":[list of methodNames]
 "otherdata":[listOfOtherData]
}
```

return map directly, or make arraylist of such maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
where: "Internal"

uriRequestReport << [ControllerSupportTest.createUrl1(), ControllerSupportTest.createUrl2()]
methodNameReport = [ControllerSupportTest.METHODNAME_FINDONE_BYID]
```