# Spock: How to use test data with @Stepwise

Tags: loops, testing, spock, geb

I used @Stepwise for automation. 8 test methods are running sequentially to complete the process. One of the methods take parameter and I want to pass different parameters to the method.

But the problem is: The method takes first set of parameter, then parameters are processed **AND** instead of proceeding to the next method, the method takes next set of parameter.

The source looks like:

```java
@Stepwise
class AOSearchPageTest extends GebReportingSpec
{
    def "first_method"()
    {
    }

    def "second_method"()
    {
        when:
        at particularPage
        then:
        process(area)
        process(coutntry)
        process(airport)
        process(dest_area)
        process(dest_coutntry)
        process(dest_airport)

        where:
        area << ["asia","europe"]
        country << ["japan","uk"]
        port << ["narita","london"]
        dest_area << ["asia","europe"]
        dest_country << ["korea","italy"]
        dest_port << ["seul","florence"]
    }

    def "third_method"()
    {
        //Some other processing
    }
```

The second method first populate with the "asia","japan","narita","asia","korea","seul"

and instead of executing "third_method"(), 
it takes second set of parameter 
europe,uk,london,europe,italy,florence.

How I can process each set of data so that all methods [defs] will be executed top to bottom for each set of data?

Comment: What exactly are you testing? There are no assertions in your test.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `@Stepwise`

```
Indicates that a spec's feature methods should be run sequentially in their declared order (even in the presence of a parallel spec runner), always starting from the first method. If a method fails, the remaining methods will be skipped. Feature methods declared in super- and subspecs are not affected.
```

`where` clause indicates that how many times your method will be executed. You can't go from one method to another without finishing it's full execution.
So, u can move your dependents tasks into one method and move some processing in your helper method to reduce line of code in your spec method.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `third_method` a private standalone method that is not executed as a test, and invoke it after the processing block in the `second_method`. Something like this:

```
@Stepwise
class AOSearchPageTest extends GebReportingSpec
{
    def "first_method"()
    {
    }

    def "second_method"()
    {
        when:
        at particularPage

        then:
        process(area)
        process(coutntry)
        process(airport)
        process(dest_area)
        process(dest_coutntry)
        process(dest_airport)

        and:
        thirdMethod()

        where:
        area << ["asia","europe"]
        country << ["japan","uk"]
        port << ["narita","london"]
        dest_area << ["asia","europe"]
        dest_country << ["korea","italy"]
        dest_port << ["seul","florence"]
    }

    private def thirdMethod()
    {
        //Some other processing
    }
```

But be careful, in this case the `thirdMethod` needs to return a boolean result which indicates a success or a fail of what was previously your `third_method` test.