# Writing DRY Spock tests

Tags: groovy, parameters, where-clause, spock

Assume that I have a Spock specification that given a city and state tests for the correct zip code.  Assume I have a text file of cities and states that is used to drive the tests in the where clause.
Now assume that I want to split the tests so that I can run for "Virginia" or "Maryland". The approach that I have taken is to create a new VirginiaSpec and a new MarylandSpec and in that spec, I modify the where clause.
This works, but seems inefficient because every other part of the VirginiaSpec and MarylandSpec is exactly the same.  In addition, if the logic changes, then I would need to change it in every spec that I have.
So what I am looking for is an approach that allows me to have one StateSpec in which the where clause can be parameterized.
I realize I have not included a code example, however if my question is not clear, then I can provide one.  Thanks for your help.
-Dan

Comment: i _assume_ *SCNR* you want https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

Comment: What you want should be easy to do. But we are on StackOverflow here - welcome, by the way. That means: You me yours and I will show you mine. Where is your code? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I can copy, compile and run. Then I can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.  You could put the basic setup and structure and even the test itself in a base test class, then extend that class w/ your `VirginiaSpec` and `MarylandSpec`.  Your spec classes would be very small probably just defining a constant that is the state for the spec.

But that seems needless.  If both the cities and states are in this file, you could just read in the file in the `where` section of your test.

https://snekse.github.io/test-often-and-prosper-slides/#/42

If you cannot get the WHERE section working, you could always read in your file during the `setupSpec` and store the data in some kind of data structure then loop through it.

[Spock: Reading Test Data from CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25189342/378151)

But in general, using the Where label is going to be the right answer.